# HAML filters in a helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filter, haml, dry

Helper functions can receive a block which they `yield` to render the block. Sometimes I'd want that block to be spec'd with a filter. So for example:

```
= doc_page title: 'FAQ' do
  :markdown
    # Welcome to the *FAQ*
```

This is not so DRY as we are always writing doc_page and markdown together. Can I make the helper method accept a block and pass it through a HAML filter. Something like:

```
= doc_page title: 'FAQ' do
  # Welcome to the *FAQ*
```

In this fantasy, `doc_page` is a helper method that does some setup stuff and then passes the content through markdown, saving us the need to declare `:markdown` everywhere and making the world a DRYer place.

Comment: This question is unclear. What exactly are you trying to do inside the helper? Render a block of Haml to HTML?

Comment: Updated the question. I'm trying make a helper which outputs a heading and then passes the block through markdown, to save having to put a separate `:markdown` declaration under the helper call every time.

Comment: Not important, but: Why pass the heading? Why not have it in `markdown` text itself? It might look more complete like that. Plus, won't it be better to have the markdown texts in separate `markdown` files and then have the helper load them instead? That will be much more elegant in my opinion. Plus it may easier to edit too as its just pure `markdown`; editors might treat the file syntax highlighting better.

Comment: @JikkuJose If you have 100 pages like this and you manually render the header, you're going to have a hard time if you ever want to change the page structure, e.g. in a simple case if you wanted to change all your headers from h2 to h3. I don't mean to over-engineer but in practice those kinds of mass-refactorings do happen every now and then ime.

Comment: @mahemoff I am sorry but I still think its elegant to have all content in markdown files; apparently thats how most static site generators like Jekyll, Middleman and mostly all others handle data.

Now, coming to your specific situation of changing the styling of the heading: Frankly, is it pretty easy to do the style change via CSS for all the page headings? Further if you really need to also, you can quite easily do a script to make the edit in all pages.

Comment: It Depends (tm). I had a case recently where I wanted to put headers on their own Bootstrap row, it wrap .row .col-md-12. around them and then separately put page body in another row. A wrapper function would've made it trivial to manipulate the page structure, versus going around to every HAML file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to use filters in helpers. An alternative approach would be to use redcarpet to parse the markdown and then pass the output to a helper.

an example would be:

```
= doc_page title: 'FAQ', :markdown do
  ### my markdown

= doc_page title: 'FAQ' do
  normal html
```

The implementation of the doc_page would be something like this:

```
def doc_page(title, markup=:html)

  content = yield

  if markup == :markdown
    markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML)
    content = markdown.render(content)
  end

  content
end
```

This would solve your problem, as you define your markdown filter in the helper. And you don't need an extra indentation level in your haml.

Answer (score 2):

You could use tilt (the api haml uses to render markdown) directly instead of through haml. Probably something like this (not tested).

```
markdown_template = Tilt['md'].new { "# this is markdown code" }
markdown_template.render
```

You can find a similar example in the [Tilt docs](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt/blob/master/docs/TEMPLATES.md#usage-8).
But this is more of an idea than a complete implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid, but it's not possible, because haml is a [preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor), basicly this piece of code:

```
= doc_page title: 'FAQ' do
  # Welcome to the *FAQ*
  %a href="/" link
```

Will be converted in runtime ruby code like:

```
concat(doc_page title: 'FAQ' do
  # Welcome to the *FAQ*
  concat('<a href="/">link</a>')
end)
```